# sql comment error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i export this sql from a drupal site through phpmyadmin

```
CREATE TABLE `admin_language` (
  `uid` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'COMMENT AS `Primary Key: Unique user ID.`,
  `language` varchar(12) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''COMMENT AS `User’s default administration language.`
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Stores user admin language selections.';
```

but when i import to another mysql through phpmyadmin, there is an error

```
    #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS 
`Primary Key: Unique user ID.`, `language` varchar(12) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''' at 
line 2
```

anyone know what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the quotes of the comments. From `` to ''

Comment: And also change  "comment as" to "comment"

Comment: is it possible to set at phpmyadmin?

Comment: If you don't need the comments you can disable them in the export. But if you need them i don't think there is a way to change the syntax. Try upgrading the phpmyadmin version in the drupal website.

Comment: phpmyadmin 4.5.5 is buggy, i changed to use 3.5.5 export the sql flawlessly